# SQLite Request showing "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied"

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a small problem with Query for my database.

```
index = 5 
letter = ["A", "C,D", "E,F", "G,H,I", "J,K,L", "M,N,O", "P,Q,R", "S,T,U", "V,W,X", "Y,Z"]
connection = sqlite3.connect("login.db")
result = connection.execute("SELECT Username, Phone, Date_of_birth FROM CLIENTS WHERE Username LIKE '[?]%'", (letter,))
```

I need to return all Users in DB which starts from Chosen letters, for example:

if Index will come as 5, DB should print all Users which starts with Letters: "M,N,O"

But I'm always getting error:
"Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied"

I can request it like this:

```
  result = connection.execute("SELECT Username, Phone, Date_of_birth FROM CLIENTS WHERE Username LIKE 'S%'")
```

and i'm getting proper result. But I need to make it work for any chosen Index.

My logic is that ? should replaced with Index(M,N,O) and everything should work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3` does not support a form of `executemany` with `select` statements. Instead, consider using a recursive `cte` with a subquery:

```
index = 5 
letter = ["A", "C,D", "E,F", "G,H,I", "J,K,L", "M,N,O", "P,Q,R", "S,T,U", "V,W,X", "Y,Z"]
connection = sqlite3.connect("login.db")
result = connection.execute(f"""
  with letters(l, r) as (
      select "{letter[index]}", ""
      union all
      select case when instr(l, ",") = 0 then "" else substr(l, instr(l, ",")+1, length(l) - instr(l, ",")) end, case when instr(l, ",") = 0 then l else substr(l, 1, instr(l, ",")-1) end from letters where length(l) > 0
  )
  select c.username, c.phone, c.date_of_birth from clients c where exists (
       select 1 from letters l where length(l.r) > 0 and substr(lower(c.username), 1, length(l.r)) == lower(l.r)
  )
  """)
```

Comment: thank you for respond. Its not showing anything. Just black DB. Even if I choose S,T,U (I have Names with S in DB)

Comment: still not showing anything. I did double check that DB have some clients with S. But still nothing.

Comment: @Sergey Can you post a sample of `clients`?

Comment: @Sergey My apologies, I misread your original question. Please see my recent edit, as I made several changes to reflect what (I think) you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Sergey Glad to help!

Comment: Hey Alex, your example is showing all records but only with Capital Letters. Can you please update it so it will show not capital as well?

Comment: @Sergey Definitely, please see my recent edit. I changed the subquery condition to be case-insensitive.

Comment: You are the best!